# Alternate Optimal Solution

Tags: optimization, simplex-method

Is there a linear optimization problem where there is an alternate optimal solution(i.e $z_j-c_j=0$) but all the $y_{ij}$ in the simplex table is negative, i.e $y_{ij}<0$?

In the linear problem of Maximization, we say an optimal solution has been achieved if $z_j-c_j>0$, but if for some $j$ we have $z_j-c_j=0$ then we have an alternate optimal solution.

[image]

Comment: Please provide some more context to your question. You have not explained any of your notation. Also, usually the simplex table only really applies to linear programs - do you mean any optimization problem or just a linear program where one applies the simplex method?

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience, I have edited my question.

Answer (score 1):

They shouldn’t be all negative, otherwise we wouldn’t have any basic variables left in the tableau as they are required to have a column of the form:

$$\begin{bmatrix}
0\\\vdots\\1\\\vdots\\0
\end{bmatrix}$$

Thus, in this type of negative-basis tableau, we would be forced to solve for basic variables and that would eventually make all of the $y_{ij}$ non-negative.

Not only that, but if we were to be in such a hypothetical situation, then the other solution we would find after pivoting would be infeasible because it would violates the non-negativity, $x_j\ge0$, constraint for the basic variables.

Thus, this situation would never arise unless some grave miscalculations took place